# Is there a reading order for Zenescope's Grimm Fairy Tales?

Tags: comics, suggested-order, grimm-fairy-tales

I've just started finally reading this series and have the first two TPBs. I'm thoroughly hooked and I see there is a ton of of various GFT titles that have been done and also currently going. I have no idea how to proceed collecting and reading this series and am worried that I'll buy something I won't understand because I didn't read some previous thing.

I haven't been able to find any kind of reading list for the series. Can I just keep collecting the main series and it will tell me what side stuff to read next? I'm overwhelmed by it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the series are stand alone series like Jungle Book and Robyn Hood but for reading the main GFT titles they go in this order

GFT volumes 1 - 8,

GFT Inferno,

GFT Dream Eater Saga Vol 1 and 2,

GFT volumes 9 - 14,

GFT Different Season volumes 1 - 3 can be read at any time.

Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

I found this wiki it might help, I too am looking for a full list but do not see any facts backing this order:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimm_Fairy_Tales_%28comics%29#Chronological_order

Comment: Could you please give a bit more information than just a link?

Answer (score 0):

When you read the comics it will tell you in an editor’s note what to read if you have missed anything during the course of the comics, hope this helps.

Comment: Nice…but could you elaborate on this answer? For example, do you happen to know the reading order that would be given in the comics?